# Libgdx with ROBOVM error - Element 'resources' is already used

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I'm building a game with Libgdx. I've been able to fix many errors, but I could not fix or find any help on this one:

I'm receiving the following error when i try to run the my Libgdx game with ROBOVM:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching ants-iosRoboVM".
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'resources'
>   is already used with
>   @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(inline=false, entry=resource,
>   name=, data=false, empty=true, type=void, required=false) on field
>   'resources' private java.util.ArrayList
>   org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.resources at line 13

The game runs fine on Desktop, Android and also in iOS with Xamarin. The presented error occurs when i try to run the program as iOS Application, using RoboVM eclipse plugin (found in http://download.robovm.org/eclipse/).

I've been able to successfully test a new application using Libgdx setup-ui JAR. Comparing the application which im trying to run with the fresh new one (which works fine), the only significant difference that i could perceive is that the real project uses others projects as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you only have one `<resources>` section in your robovm.xml file in the project root. If there are several `<resources>` sections then you need to merge them into one.